# Docker Nginx | Where are the configs file?

Tags: docker, nginx, http-live-streaming, nginx-rtmp

I'm a brand-new Docker user, and despite my research on the internet, I can't find the configuration files or even the Nginx directory on my server (Debian 11). I'm using rtmp-hls to create a stream server, but without access to the config file it's impossible to use it properly.

In which directories can I find these configuration files?

Comment: Did you pull Debian image from docker hub? Are you using dockerfile or docker-compose yml?

Answer (score 0):

you need to go inside  container with command: docker exec -it container_name bash
and try to find there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).